# Add to array in Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema model that looks like the below example. The accounts field is an array of account IDs.

```
var ListingSchema = new Schema({
  listing: { type: String, required: true },
  admin: { type: String, required: true, index: true },
  accounts: [{ type: String, index: true }]
});
```

Now in my Node/Express backend, I add an entry like so:

```
Listing.create({
  listing: req.body.id,
  admin: req.session.userID,
  account: req.session.userID
}, function (err){ 
  if (err) throw err;
  else res.send({success:true});
});
```

However I'm not adding to the account field correctly because it's an array. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

For a create try this:

```
var accounts = [req.session.userID];

Listing.create({
  listing: req.body.id,
  admin: req.session.userID,
  accounts: accounts 
}, function (err){ 
  if (err) throw err;
  else res.send({success:true});
});
```

For an update try this:

```
{ $push: { accounts: 'value' }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var accounts = [req.session.userID];
```

And

```
accounts: [{ type: String, index: true }]
```

should be

```
accounts: [{ type: Array, index: true }]
```